# Generating URL from amazon s3 (streaming files from amazon s3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, c#-4.0

I have a problem trying to download files from amazon s3. I have files stored on amazom s3 and to access these files, users need to be authenticated. I'm trying to find a way to stream files without downloading each file from amazon onto my server and then from my server to the end client. I just want to be able to stream the file direct by generating the url, can you suggest some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I have a solution for this exact scenario.

Basically, you want to present a file that is stored on Amazon S3 to the user's browser in such a way that it forces the download rather than opening in the browser window. Typically, if you store the file locally on the server then this is simple to do. But, you don't want to have to first download the file to your server from S3 just to send it over to the client, so...

You'll need the Amazon S3 SDK installed which you can get from Nuget here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.S3/

Also, make sure you're referencing these namespaces:

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
```

Here's the code that I use to force download a remote file on Amazon S3:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

GetObjectRequest getObjRequest = new GetObjectRequest {
BucketName = "**yourbucketname**",
Key = "**yourobjectkey**"
}; 

IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client("**youraccesskeyid**", "**yoursecretkey**", RegionEndpoint.EUWest2); //< set your own region

using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(getObjRequest))
    using (Stream stream = response.ResponseStream)
            {
                int bytesRead = 0;

                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(response.Key));
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", response.ContentLength.ToString());
                Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";

                while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0 && Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    Response.OutputStream.Flush();
                    buffer = new byte[4096];
                }
            }
```

As always, I'm sure there are better ways of accomplishing this, but this code works for me.

Answer (score -1):

AWS provides SDK for .Net which will let them download (and upload files).
For example here: http://ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/s3/csharp/

A quick google should give you the answer. If there is something specific which you are unable to do, then please explain your question a little more.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? Didn't the SDK work for you?